# Script runs in Unity Preview but not on HoloLens

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm new to C#, HoloLens, and Unity. I want to add the voice command functionality from [Holograms 101](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/holograms_101) to [Holograms 230](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/holograms_230).

Having completed Holograms 230, I've taken the SpeechManager script from Holograms 101, added some `Debug.Log` commands, and dragged it onto an object in Unity's "Hierarchy" panel. When I click the "Play" button in Unity, my script runs (as verified by the fact that my `Debug.Log` appears in the status bar). But when I build and deploy it to the HoloLens (via "Debug -> Start Debugging" in Visual Studio), the `Debug.Log`s from my new script don't show up in Visual Studio's "Output" panel, even through `Debug.Log`s from other scripts do.

Here's my SpeechManager.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Windows.Speech;

public class SpeechManager : MonoBehaviour {

    KeywordRecognizer keywordRecognizer = null;
    Dictionary<string, System.Action> keywords = new Dictionary<string, System.Action>();

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Debug.Log("!!Starting speech manager");
        keywords.Add("Place item", () =>
        {
            Debug.Log("!!Place item");
        });

        // Tell the KeywordRecognizer about our keywords.
        keywordRecognizer = new KeywordRecognizer(keywords.Keys.ToArray());

        // Register a callback for the KeywordRecognizer and start recognizing!
        keywordRecognizer.OnPhraseRecognized += KeywordRecognizer_OnPhraseRecognized;
        keywordRecognizer.Start();
    }

    private void KeywordRecognizer_OnPhraseRecognized(PhraseRecognizedEventArgs args)
    {
        System.Action keywordAction;
        if (keywords.TryGetValue(args.text, out keywordAction))
        {
            keywordAction.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's another script, attached to the same object in Unity, that functions correctly and triggers `Debug.Log`s:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Windows.Speech;
using Academy.HoloToolkit.Unity;

/// <summary>
/// The SurfaceManager class allows applications to scan the environment for a specified amount of time 
/// and then process the Spatial Mapping Mesh (find planes, remove vertices) after that time has expired.
/// </summary>
public class PlaySpaceManager : Singleton<PlaySpaceManager>
{
    [Tooltip("When checked, the SurfaceObserver will stop running after a specified amount of time.")]
    public bool limitScanningByTime = true;

    [Tooltip("How much time (in seconds) that the SurfaceObserver will run after being started; used when 'Limit Scanning By Time' is checked.")]
    public float scanTime = 30.0f;

    [Tooltip("Material to use when rendering Spatial Mapping meshes while the observer is running.")]
    public Material defaultMaterial;

    [Tooltip("Optional Material to use when rendering Spatial Mapping meshes after the observer has been stopped.")]
    public Material secondaryMaterial;

    [Tooltip("Minimum number of floor planes required in order to exit scanning/processing mode.")]
    public uint minimumFloors = 1;

    [Tooltip("Minimum number of wall planes required in order to exit scanning/processing mode.")]
    public uint minimumWalls = 1;

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates if processing of the surface meshes is complete.
    /// </summary>
    private bool meshesProcessed = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// GameObject initialization.
    /// </summary>
    private void Start()
    {
        // Update surfaceObserver and storedMeshes to use the same material during scanning.
        SpatialMappingManager.Instance.SetSurfaceMaterial(defaultMaterial);

        // Register for the MakePlanesComplete event.
        SurfaceMeshesToPlanes.Instance.MakePlanesComplete += SurfaceMeshesToPlanes_MakePlanesComplete;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called once per frame.
    /// </summary>
    private void Update()
    {
        // Check to see if the spatial mapping data has been processed
        // and if we are limiting how much time the user can spend scanning.
        if (!meshesProcessed && limitScanningByTime)
        {
            // If we have not processed the spatial mapping data
            // and scanning time is limited...

            // Check to see if enough scanning time has passed
            // since starting the observer.
            if (limitScanningByTime && ((Time.time - SpatialMappingManager.Instance.StartTime) < scanTime))
            {
                // If we have a limited scanning time, then we should wait until
                // enough time has passed before processing the mesh.
            }
            else
            {
                // The user should be done scanning their environment,
                // so start processing the spatial mapping data...

                /* TODO: 3.a DEVELOPER CODING EXERCISE 3.a */

                // 3.a: Check if IsObserverRunning() is true on the
                // SpatialMappingManager.Instance.
                if (SpatialMappingManager.Instance.IsObserverRunning())
                {
                    // 3.a: If running, Stop the observer by calling
                    // StopObserver() on the SpatialMappingManager.Instance.
                    SpatialMappingManager.Instance.StopObserver();
                    Debug.Log("!!Stop Observer!!");
                }

                // 3.a: Call CreatePlanes() to generate planes.
                CreatePlanes();

                // 3.a: Set meshesProcessed to true.
                meshesProcessed = true;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handler for the SurfaceMeshesToPlanes MakePlanesComplete event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">Source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="args">Args for the event.</param>
    private void SurfaceMeshesToPlanes_MakePlanesComplete(object source, System.EventArgs args)
    {
        /* TODO: 3.a DEVELOPER CODING EXERCISE 3.a */

        // Collection of floor and table planes that we can use to set horizontal items on.
        List<GameObject> horizontal = new List<GameObject>();

        // Collection of wall planes that we can use to set vertical items on.
        List<GameObject> vertical = new List<GameObject>();

        // 3.a: Get all floor and table planes by calling
        // SurfaceMeshesToPlanes.Instance.GetActivePlanes().
        // Assign the result to the 'horizontal' list.
        horizontal = SurfaceMeshesToPlanes.Instance.GetActivePlanes(PlaneTypes.Table | PlaneTypes.Floor);

        // 3.a: Get all wall planes by calling
        // SurfaceMeshesToPlanes.Instance.GetActivePlanes().
        // Assign the result to the 'vertical' list.
        vertical = SurfaceMeshesToPlanes.Instance.GetActivePlanes(PlaneTypes.Wall);

        // Check to see if we have enough horizontal planes (minimumFloors)
        // and vertical planes (minimumWalls), to set holograms on in the world.
        if (horizontal.Count >= minimumFloors && vertical.Count >= minimumWalls)
        {
            // We have enough floors and walls to place our holograms on...

            // 3.a: Let's reduce our triangle count by removing triangles
            // from SpatialMapping meshes that intersect with our active planes.
            // Call RemoveVertices().
            // Pass in all activePlanes found by SurfaceMeshesToPlanes.Instance.
            RemoveVertices(SurfaceMeshesToPlanes.Instance.ActivePlanes);

            // 3.a: We can indicate to the user that scanning is over by
            // changing the material applied to the Spatial Mapping meshes.
            // Call SpatialMappingManager.Instance.SetSurfaceMaterial().
            // Pass in the secondaryMaterial.
            SpatialMappingManager.Instance.SetSurfaceMaterial(secondaryMaterial);

            // 3.a: We are all done processing the mesh, so we can now
            // initialize a collection of Placeable holograms in the world
            // and use horizontal/vertical planes to set their starting positions.
            // Call SpaceCollectionManager.Instance.GenerateItemsInWorld().
            // Pass in the lists of horizontal and vertical planes that we found earlier.
            SpaceCollectionManager.Instance.GenerateItemsInWorld(horizontal, vertical);
        }
        else
        {
            // We do not have enough floors/walls to place our holograms on...

            // 3.a: Re-enter scanning mode so the user can find more surfaces by 
            // calling StartObserver() on the SpatialMappingManager.Instance.
            SpatialMappingManager.Instance.StartObserver();

            // 3.a: Re-process spatial data after scanning completes by
            // re-setting meshesProcessed to false.
            meshesProcessed = false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates planes from the spatial mapping surfaces.
    /// </summary>
    private void CreatePlanes()
    {
        // Generate planes based on the spatial map.
        SurfaceMeshesToPlanes surfaceToPlanes = SurfaceMeshesToPlanes.Instance;
        if (surfaceToPlanes != null && surfaceToPlanes.enabled)
        {
            surfaceToPlanes.MakePlanes();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes triangles from the spatial mapping surfaces.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="boundingObjects"></param>
    private void RemoveVertices(IEnumerable<GameObject> boundingObjects)
    {
        RemoveSurfaceVertices removeVerts = RemoveSurfaceVertices.Instance;
        if (removeVerts != null && removeVerts.enabled)
        {
            removeVerts.RemoveSurfaceVerticesWithinBounds(boundingObjects);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the GameObject is unloaded.
    /// </summary>
    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (SurfaceMeshesToPlanes.Instance != null)
        {
            SurfaceMeshesToPlanes.Instance.MakePlanesComplete -= SurfaceMeshesToPlanes_MakePlanesComplete;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing looks obviously wrong.  You can implement an `OnDestroy()` method for `SpeechManager` with a log in it to see if the object is getting destroyed for some reason.

Comment: Have you checked the Microphone capability in Player Settings?

Comment: @Foggzie Thanks for the suggestion! Adding a `void OnDestroy()` with a log in it had no effect.

Comment: @RCYR Good question! Yes, the Microphone capability is checked.

Comment: You mention _"when I build and deploy it to the HoloLens (via "Debug -> Start Debugging" in Visual Studio)"_.  Are you actually re-building the project in Unity and then doing that or are you just clicking that menu item in Visual Studio?  If you make changes to the project, you need to rebuild it first in Unity _and then_ debug from Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes. In Unity, I'm using File -> Build Settings -> Build to rebuild between deployments.